# preg_replace <*>

Tags: php, preg-replace

How do I change all occurrences of `<*>` in every line of a text file (a total of 5 `<*>` in every line) using `preg_replace` (substituting it with, say, `|`)?

My code is:

```
preg_replace("/<*\>/", "|", $text);
```

Comment: The code of what have you tried can be useful

Comment: My code is: preg_replace("/<*\>/", "|", $text). Well, I'm a complete newbie in PHP, though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit your question in order to improve it

Comment: is it actually really `<*>` or does that mean, that it can be any (valid) html tag? `<div><h3><p><span>... `

Comment: It's actually the next stage after I've finished my Symbian app, the text file is uploaded to the server and then I need to parse the string in each line and insert it into MySQL. Oh my, I regret I never learnt PHP & MySQL really hard in the past. The truth is, I don't need to substitute the "<*>" with any character, I'd rather split each part of the line and load each of them into the database.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, yes, it's really <*>. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

You shoud escape the `*`

```
preg_replace("/<\*>/", "|", $text);
```

Comment: This didn't work. Editted my code just now. $new_text = preg_replace("/<\\*>/", '|', $current_text);

Comment: @user2083506 Do you really want to replace **<*>** in a text? Like: before: __I'm loving this symbols really: <*>__ after: __I'm loving this symbols really: |__ (At me it works perfect)

Comment: It might work with just one "<*>". Haven't given that a try, anyway. But there are a total of 5 <*>'s in each line (hundreds and even thousands of lines). BTW, how come it didn't work for me?

Comment: @user2083506 Try this `str_replace('<*>', '|', $text);` And if you want an answer TRY it with one "<*>"!

Comment: I googled all day today, and I "figured out" and str_replace only replaces one character, am I right?

Comment: No, str_replace didn't work, either. Just tried that just now and earlier this afternoon (in my place).

Comment: No that's wrong, str_replace replaces as many characters as you want. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: I mean, it doesn't replace two or more same or different characters put together in a row. You know what I mean, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, I looked up this link, too... hours before I signed up with  this site. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Here are 2 lines picked from the said text file I've successfully uploaded through my app.
20130218 13:37:09<*>aaa-Ibu<*>+6200000000<*>Sae, Th, mdh2an urg lgkg tenang pm wng.<*>1<*>2
20130218 13:28:54<*>aaa-Ibu<*>+6200000000<*>00:01:20<*>2<*>1

Comment: At me this worked `echo str_replace('<*>', '|', "20130218 13:37:09<*>aaa-Ibu<*>+6200000000<*>Sae, Th, mdh2an urg lgkg tenang pm wng.<*>1<*>2 20130218 13:28:54<*>aaa-Ibu<*>+6200000000<*>00:01:20<*>2<*>1");`

Comment: foreach($lines as $line_no=>$line)
  {$new_line = str_replace('<*>', '|', $line);
   echo $new_line."<br>";
  } No luck...

Comment: The culprit was actually in the type/encoding of string. It was Unicode. When I used an ANSI (ISO-8859-1), "explode()" could get the job done.